# Try to get an access_token with google oauth api but redirect to `o/oauth2/approval`

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I'm now trying to use google oauth api to allow google user to login to my app. And I've followed all along with google's [OAuth2Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) documentation.

I used this to get a code and it worked just fine.

```
var u = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'
    + '&response_type=code'
    + '&client_id=' + opts.googleClient
    + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI
    + '&scope=' + opts.scope
    + '&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline';
```

But while I try to get the access_token with the `/o/oauth2/token` api like below:

```
    var u = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?'
        + 'code=' + code
        + '&client_id=' + opts.googleClient
        + '&client_secret=' + opts.googleSecret
        + '&scope='
        + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI
        + '&grant_type=' + 'authorization_code';
    request.post({url: u, json: true}, fn);
```

It returned me

```
{
    error: "invalid_request"
}
```

I've checked that with Chrome developer tools in the Network bar which indicate that the request URL is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=-5013c18c497345fc&hl=en&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUcwS1TxlojrAPVNCj7ntTlz1H4xQgysC` instead of what I'm posting to.

I can make sure my post url and data looks exactly like that in [Google oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). But the result is totally different.

Did I doing anything wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are sending looks correct, but it looks like there are two errors in how the request is formed.

First, when you construct the form data part of the message make sure that you URL encode all of the values, e.g. if the redirect_uri value contains an &, that will cause you problems unless it is URL encoded.

Second, while you are correctly doing a POST instead of a GET, you are still sending the parameters in the query string instead of in the body of the request. Move them to the body, set the content-type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and you should be set.

(it looks like JavaScript, but I'm not sure which libraries you are using so I didn't provide sample code)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually using nodejs and here's my code on  [github gist](https://gist.github.com/fraserxu/5881632).

I've tried to use a node module called `request` to make a `application.x-www-form-urlencoded` call but got the same result. Can you help check if there's something wrong with my parameters and body. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the "scope" from the form data, and move the "code=" out of the URL, into the form data.

Comment: It works! Thank u sooo much. It turns out that google only support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type. But I don't get why it works in their oauthPlayground.

Thanks anyway!